# Alphabet tracing activity in js

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I am trying to figure out a way to code a letter tracing activity for kids wherein the user has to press and move the cursor, and along the cursor's pointer the alphabet gets colored. I tried using svg's stroke-dashedoffset attribute to color the insides of the svg along the pointer's position.

```js
var svg = document.querySelectorAll('svg g line');


var elem1 = document.querySelector("#svg_2");
var elem2 = document.querySelector("#svg_3");

var len1 = svg[0].getTotalLength()
var len2 = svg[1].getTotalLength()

let mouseDraw = false

// only tackling the left stroke of the alphabet 'v' for now

elem1.addEventListener("mousedown", (evt) => {
    // console.log('mousedown')
    
  mouseDraw = true
})

elem1.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
    // console.log('mouseup')
    mouseDraw = false
    
})


elem1.addEventListener('mousemove', (evt) => {
        if(mouseDraw){
    // console.log('mousemove')
            var e = evt.target;
    var dim = e.getBoundingClientRect();
        var y = evt.pageY - dim.height;
    // console.log(y);
    svg[2].style.strokeDashoffset = y + 'px';
            
        }
})
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg width="640" height="480" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <!-- Created with SVG-edit - https://github.com/SVG-Edit/svgedit-->
 <g class="layer1">
  <title>Layer 1</title>
  <line fill="none" id="svg_2" stroke="#bbb" stroke-width="10" x1="213" x2="248" y1="134" y2="226" st/>
  <line fill="none" id="svg_3" stroke="#bbb" stroke-width="10" x1="249" x2="297" y1="226" y2="133"/>
 </g>
    <g class="layer2">
  <title>Layer 1</title>
  <line fill="none" id="svg_2" stroke="#000" stroke-width="10" x1="213" x2="248" y1="134" y2="226" style="stroke-dashoffset:98.4px;stroke-dasharray:98.4px"/>
  <line fill="none" id="svg_3" stroke="#000" stroke-width="10" x1="249" x2="297" y1="226" y2="133" style="stroke-dashoffset:104.6px;stroke-dasharray:104.6px"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```

What I' struggling is to map the pointer's position accurately. Any help in this regard is very much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Your question is hard to understand... Please try to formulate it in a more concrete way: requirement - current pituation - desired result.

Comment: I want to trace svg using mouse pointer position to be something like (desired result) : [link] (https://pschool.in/writing/capital-letters) . I have created a code pen to give you an idea as to how the current situation is [link] (https://codepen.io/harish123/pen/PoKXQJG)